# Is deliverability negatively impacted by using accent marks in an SFMC Sender Profile?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability

I am working with a global client who wants to set up sender profiles in the language of each of their divisions. Some of these sender profiles would contain accent marks. Does anyone have experience with deliverability using sender profiles with these special characters? (all of the emails are UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer to it affecting deliverability as each client has a different filter - but in general I would say it is unlikely to affect deliverability and if it does, it would be minimally.([ref](https://www.experian.com/assets/cheetahmail/white-papers/symbols-in-subject-lines-cheetahmail.pdf) - look at page 9, I know this is about subject lines, but should be same as From Name)

The major issue would be rendering of the characters, not all clients can correctly render UTF symbols (which letters with accent marks are considered) so they may not appear correctly. ([ref](https://www.quora.com/How-is-email-deliverability-affected-by-symbols-in-subject-lines-like-stars-hearts-etc-Example-http-myteamconnects-com-stars-subject-lines-No-need-to-comment-on-and-Im-talking-about-image-type-symbols-and-how-to-apply-them) - I know this is concerning subject lines, but that should have the same rendering as From Name)